# Problem in getting week number of sundays , in zend

Tags: zend-framework

I want to get the week number of a particular date , using Zend_Date

My local is setted as English(IN) [en_IN], in Opera browser

I am using the following code

```
$date = new Zend_Date('22 Mar, 2010', null, Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale'));
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::WEEK); //output 12, correct
```

But if we give a sunday , it will not work correctly

for example

```
$date = new Zend_Date('21 Mar, 2010', null, Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale'));
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::WEEK); //output 11,  not correct
```

it should output 12

What is wrong with this?

Comment: You should submit this as a bug on the bug tracker if it's not working correctly.

Comment: If 21:st is a Sunday, the 22:nd is a Monday = new week, at least by Swedish standards. Do English weeks start with a Sunday?

Comment: In the United States, Sunday is the first day of the week.  I don't know what other locales follow that rule.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report with Zend as Goran has suggested?

Answer (score 1):

For the Locale of English (India), 'en_IN', the first day of the week is Monday.  `Zend_Date` is giving you the correct value.

**EDIT:** I just did a quick test using the 'en_US' locale, and I'm getting the same behavior.  It looks like `Zend_Date` may be ignoring the locale for this calculation.

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_US');
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);

$date = new Zend_Date('2010-03-22', null, Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale'));
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::WEEK); //outputs 12, correct
$date = new Zend_Date('2010-03-21', null, Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale'));
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::WEEK); //outputs 11, not correct
```

Comment: I also think that Zend_Date may be ignoring the locale for this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_IN');
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);

$date = new Zend_Date('22 Mar, 2010', null, Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale'));
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::WEEK);
```

If not, try to determine it directly, using `Zend_Locale_Data`. Sometimes data provided by Unicode are not exactly as we expect for our region.